# iPhone combo box

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a combo box for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533231/creating-a-combo-box-for-the-iphone)

how to create a combobox in iphone ?

Comment: Might help if you can tell us what language you are using... iPhone SDK... HTML?

Answer (score 3):

I use a modified `UIActionSheet` with a `UIPickerView` embedded.  Check out how they handled it in this question: [Fitting a UIDatePicker into a UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349858/fitting-a-uidatepicker-into-a-uiactionsheet).

You could also use a simple `UITableView` embedded in some sort of "pop-up" or modal view.